# How to do rails inner join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to join two tables by reference number.  They are independent tables so neither one is a child of the other.  Please let me know if you see where my mistake is.

```
 raw_data = table_1.where(uid: uid).where(sql_statement_for_recent_records('table_1s'))
 data = @raw_data.joins('JOIN table_2s ON table_2s.reference_number = table_1s.reference_number')

 def sql_statement_for_recent_records(table_name)
       "#{table_name}.created_at > '#{Time.now - 30.seconds}'"
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that what you have. This solutions worked for me:

```
Thing = class for table 1
Thang = class for table 2

Thang.joins("inner join things on things.reference_number=thangs.reference_number).where("thangs.created_at > ?", Time.now - 30.seconds)
```